# Telerik Themes not working in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, telerik, themes

I have seen some similar questions but all of the answers are the same and aren't working for myself,

I am trying to use Telerik themes in a WPF/VB.net application but the themes do not set and I am unsure why,

I've tried using the following code below to achieve what I am trying to do:

```
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = New VistaTheme()
StyleManager.SetTheme(rad_button, New VistaTheme)
```

(I am using VistaTheme as an example, I have tried the code with all of the available themes)

Any help or advice would be appriciated (even in c#)!

Comment: Try add also 'InitializeComponent()'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call after  change style `InitializeComponent()` method.

```
StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = New VistaTheme()
StyleManager.SetTheme(rad_button, New VistaTheme)
InitializeComponent()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have already tried this but it still isn't working